# VsCode Go extension debugs Example_c.c file instead of actual file

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I just tried to execute a Hello World from VSCode 1.28.2 (Windows 8.1) in a C:\Scripts\hello_world.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, Gopher!")
}
```

My environment is as follows:

- I installed Go from scratch using the Windows installer:

> ```
> $ go version
> go version go1.11.2 windows/amd64
> ```

- Installed on C:\Go
- Installed VSCode Go Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.Go
- Installed debugger:

> go get -u github.com/derekparker/delve/cmd/dlv

- Checked with SystemPropertiesAdvanced:

  - Local Variable GOPATH = %USERPROFILE%\go
  - Local Variable PATH adds %USERPROFILE%\go\bin
  - System Variable PATH adds C:\Go\bin
  - System Variable GOROOT = C:\Go\
- I have MinGW64, GitBash and MinGW 1.0 (However I don't see how that could affect running Go from VSCode)
- Running from cmd.exe runs the program without problems at all:

> ```
> C:\Scripts>go run hello_world.go
> Hello, Gopher!
> ```

In VSCode settings my global go.gopath and go.goroot settings are:

```
  // Specify GOPATH here to override the one that is set as environment variable. The inferred GOPATH from workspace root overrides this, if go.inferGopath is set to true.
  "go.gopath": null

  // Specifies the GOROOT to use when no environment variable is set.
  "go.goroot": null
```

So I customized the variables from VSCode as follows:

```
{
    "editor.renderControlCharacters": false,
    "go.inferGopath": true,
    "go.goroot": "C:\\go",
}
```

Now this is the weird part. When I hit Ctrl+F5 compilation takes a "Example_c.c" file (?) and reports errors with that file (which I never created or even knew that existed):

```
# _/c_/Scripts
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build530760830\b001\_x003.o: In function `main':
./Example_c.c:1: multiple definition of `main'
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build530760830\b001\_cgo_main.o:/tmp/go-build/_cgo_main.c:1: first defined here
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build530760830\b001\_x004.o: In function `main':
./Test_C-01.c:3: multiple definition of `main'
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build530760830\b001\_cgo_main.o:/tmp/go-build/_cgo_main.c:1: first defined here
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build530760830\b001\_x005.o: In function `main':
./Test_C-02.c:3: multiple definition of `main'
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build530760830\b001\_cgo_main.o:/tmp/go-build/_cgo_main.c:1: first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
# _/c_/Scripts
Example_c.c: In function 'main':
Example_c.c:2:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'printf'
Example_c.c:4:19: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'malloc'
Example_c.c:9:3: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'free'
exit status 2
Process exiting with code: 1
```

I already tried deleting all my temporary files and restarted VsCode multiple times. The whole experience to setup a Go environment to debug a hello world is really dissapointing.

What else can I check? Any hints?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/GOPATH-in-the-VS-Code-Go-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GOPATH should point to "C:\Scripts". Then point the "program" variable in launch.json to "C:\Scripts" to run it in Debug Mode.